# SSH Login to AWS EC2 Error: packet_write_wait: Connection to x.x.x.x port 22: Broken pipe

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

Can someone please help me figure out what's going on here?

I keep trying to ssh in to an EC2 instance, that I was able to access yesterday, but I keep getting this error: "packet_write_wait: Connection to x.x.x.x port 22: Broken pipe." The last few lines of my debug output are this:

```
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug3: send packet: type 1
packet_write_wait: Connection to x.x.x.x port 22: Broken pipe
```

I'm wondering if I did not properly close the connection yesterday, and that has something to do with it. Either way, I can't log in to this EC2 instance at all now, and I'm wondering how to resolve this. I've already tried adding this to my ~/.ssh/config:

```
Host *
    ServerAliveInterval 30
    ServerAliveCountMax 5
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, and spent several hours troubleshooting.

If you're attempting to SSH from a VMware VM while NAT'ed, It is possible that SSH is dropping due to QoS flag. See this article: https://communities.vmware.com/thread/590825

The fix for me was to add the following to my client ssh config (eg ~/.ssh/config):

```
Host *
     IPQoS lowdelay throughput
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding this to `~/.ssh/config`:

```
 Host *
  TCPKeepAlive yes
  ServerAliveInterval 120
```

> **TCPKeepAlive** - Specifies whether the system should send TCP keepalive
>   messages to the other side. If they are sent, death of the connection
>   or crash of one of the machines will be properly noticed. However,
>   this means that connections will die if the route is down temporarily,
>   and some people find it annoying (The default is 'yes').
>
> **ServerAliveInterval** - Sets a timeout interval in seconds after which
>   if no data has been received from the server, ssh(1) will send a
>   message through the encrypted channel to request a response from the
>   server. The default is 0, indicating that these messages will not be
>   sent to the server.

Also trying adding the same to `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`.

Comment: Are you able to `ping` your EC2 instance?

Comment: Yes. No packet loss. Also, the "checks" Amazon runs against EC2 instances have all passed.

Comment: Can you ssh with the ip instead of the host name?

Answer (score 0):

It is often the case that we set wrong ChrootDirectory in /etc/ssh/sshd_config. The folder should contain all root utilities, i.e. it must have /bin/bash and all the required libraries. For my case, I set the directory for the user guess as following. Removing such a setting makes me able to ssh under the user guess.

```
Match user guess
  ChrootDirectory /home/guess
```